# Pandas in VS Code: AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'ascii_letters'

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

I'm a new learner in data science. I havent find out why I got an attribute error. I used python 3.8.3 in Visual Studio Code. I installed Pandas in terminal (pip install Pandas). I dont know what the problem is. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame()
print(df)
```

All I did was to create an empty dataframe. And I got that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Fatma Elik/Documents/VS Code/BTK/Pandas_dataframe.py", line 20, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\Fatma Elik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    import pandas.testing
  File "C:\Users\Fatma Elik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\testing.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pandas._testing import (
  File "C:\Users\Fatma Elik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\_testing.py", line 404, in <module>
    RANDS_CHARS = np.array(list(string.ascii_letters + string.digits), dtype=(np.str_, 1))
AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'ascii_letters'
```

Secondly I tried this instead and  I got an attribute error again:

```
import pandas as pd
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
s1=pd.Series([3,2,0,1])
s2=pd.Series([0,3,7,2])
    
data=dict(apples=s1,oranges=s2)     
    
df=pd.DataFrame(data) 
print(df)
```

Comment: Do you have a file called `string.py` in the same folder as your `Pandas_dataframe.py` script?  If so, try renaming `string.py`.

Comment: I  have `string.py ` only in setup folders. `Pandas_dataframe.py` is in my project files which is in a different place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did Ctrl+Click on `string` and I find that I already created a py file before. Because  I searched on file search engine Windows 10 before, I couldnt have found it. Another simple mistake again :)

Comment: So, I am right? Just because you had created a file name 'string'?

Comment: Yes you were right. But I couldnt find that file in the first place so I thought there isnt any

Answer (score 0):

It's a little weird, the "string" module is a part of the standard library. Could you try this code?

```
from string import ascii_letters
print(ascii_letters)
```

Check it works or not, if it doesn't work, can you enter into this file:
"C:\Users\Fatma Elik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\string.py", and can you find:

```
ascii_lowercase = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
ascii_uppercase = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
ascii_letters = ascii_lowercase + ascii_uppercase
```

It should be located from line 25 to 27. If you can't find it, you should try to upgrade your python or reinstall it.

Comment: I coded   `from string import ascii_letters print(ascii_letters)` but I saw `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Fatma Elik/Documents/VS Code/BTK/Pandas_dataframeeee.py", line 28, in <module>
    from string import ascii_letters
ImportError: cannot import name 'ascii_letters' from 'string' (c:\Users\Fatma Elik\Documents\VS Code\BTK\string.py)`

Comment: But in  `string.py` I saw  `import _string

# Some strings for ctype-style character classification
whitespace = ' \t\n\r\v\f'
ascii_lowercase = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
ascii_uppercase = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
ascii_letters = ascii_lowercase + ascii_uppercase
digits = '0123456789'
hexdigits = digits + 'abcdef' + 'ABCDEF'
octdigits = '01234567'
punctuation = r"""!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~"""
printable = digits + ascii_letters + punctuation + whitespace
`

Comment: Try to Ctrl+Click on 'ascii_letters', to confirm whether can you go to the string.py file, and what's the location it is.

Comment: When I used Jupyter Notebook there was no problem. I could see outputs. Again I cannot make  connections but at least I find a way to continue.

Comment: It seems like the environment caused it, try to Ctrl+Click on 'string', I think you had imported the wrong module of 'string'. do you have created a python file named 'string'?

Comment: Try this code: import string print(string.__file__), to verify which "string" module you are importing.

Comment: Hey guys, give me feedback, please. I am also very interested in this problem.

Comment: When I did Ctrl+Click on 'ascii_letters' **in VS** it says 'no matching results'

Comment: What about: import string print(string.__file__)? which "string" module it looking for?