# parameter gather is not used

Tags: python, pandas, default-parameters

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime

path = "/Users/tommasomasaracchio/Documents/pythonfolder"


def key_stats(gather="Total Deb/Equity (mrg)"):
    statspath = path + '/KeyStats'
    stock_list = [x[0] for x in os.walk(statspath)]
    print(stock_list)


key_stats()
```

I thought the problem was gather but it seems not to be the case.
the terminal tells me this, and I don't really understand it

```
tommaso desktop % python programma.py
hello world
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tommasomasaracchio/Desktop/programma.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/Users/tommasomasaracchio/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 179, in <module>
    import pandas.testing
  File "/Users/tommasomasaracchio/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/testing.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pandas._testing import (
  File "/Users/tommasomasaracchio/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_testing/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from pandas._testing._io import (  # noqa:F401
  File "/Users/tommasomasaracchio/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_testing/_io.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas._testing._random import rands
  File "/Users/tommasomasaracchio/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_testing/_random.py", line 10, in <module>
    RANDS_CHARS = np.array(list(string.ascii_letters + string.digits), dtype=(np.str_, 1))
AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'ascii_letters'
```

Comment: It's not that you can't use `gather` it's that you don't use `gather`. You set it with a default in the function definition and then never use the variable. Just delete it and the warning will disappear. Same with pandas. You import the library but you don't use it anywhere. Just comment it out or delete it and the warning will go away.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62745512/pandas-in-vs-code-attributeerror-module-string-has-no-attribute-ascii-lette

Comment: I haven't used pandas  in that code yet, so I don't think it's a duplicate

Comment: Sure you have. `import pandas as pd` That imports pandas.

Comment: oh, now I saw that the code functions perfectly well if I delete all the import. but still I don't understand why importing cause all those problems